# I am binding gridview in RowCommand but it is not firing RowDataBound plesae

Tags: c#, gridview, rowdatabound, rowcommand

I am binding gridview in RowCommand but it is not firing RowDataBound plesae help.

binding gridview in RowCommand

```
protected void gdServerAccess_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
       serverClassobj.DeleteRequest(strServerAccessGUID);
       gdServerAccess.DataSource = serverClassobj.GetUserServerAcceessList(Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"]));
       gdServerAccess.DataBind();
}
```

I want the RowDataBound to be fired as i have to change labels there as the Row Command deletes a record

Comment: Did you set `OnRowDataBound` on client side?

Comment: yes i have also the RowdataBound is fired all the times except from here in RowCommand anything related to postbacks or something ?